# Object doesn't move when assign to Armature

Tags: objects, armature

i've been doing a tutorial from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSodc-kkneg) and everything was perfect but when i assigned the object to the bone it doesn't move, i've been looking a lot on internet and didn't find solutions

I appreciate all your help

Thanks

This is the project

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, your link doesn't work, could you please use another platform?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i edited the post

Comment: so if I select for example the upper arm object, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, select the upper arm bone, then Ctrl P > Bone, it works fine for me, is it what you're doing?

Comment: As I see in your file, you have the vertex groups already created and the objects parented to the armature, but you don't have any points assigned to the vertex groups, provided you want to use this method. The method that @moonboots recommended might be better.

Comment: No, i've been following the tutorial, but he doesn't do that, i did what you told me, though. and it works now it moves! thanks